# Using javascript to change span to input (viceversa) and then AJAX the updated input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have this code as my span:

```
 <span class="subheading">
 <span id="loadNum"><?php echo $status ?></span>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <i class="fa fa-question-circle" rel="tooltip" title="Click on your status to change it." id="blah"></i>
 </span>
```

Now I am using this code as for the javascript:

```
    <script>
       var switchToInput = function () {
        var $input = $("<input>", {
            val: $(this).text(),
            type: "text",
            style: "color: #000"
        });
        $input.attr("ID", "loadNum");
        $(this).replaceWith($input);
        $input.on("blur", switchToSpan);
        $input.select();
    };
    var switchToSpan = function () {
        var $span = $("<span>", {
            text: $(this).val()
        });
        $span.attr("ID", "loadNum");
        $(this).replaceWith($span);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"includes/ajaxprocess.php",
            data:{status: status},
            success:function(data){
               $("#info").html(data);
            }

        });
        $span.on("click", switchToInput);
    }
    $("#loadNum").on("click", switchToInput);
</script>
```

And last but not least
ajaxprocess.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("blogger");

$status=$_POST["status"];

$query=mysql_query("UPDATE blog_members (status) values('$status') ");

if($query){
    echo "Your status has been updated";
}
else{
    echo "Error in updating your status";
}
?>
```

But when I update my status, and let the input become a span, the field of the DB doesn't update. How could I make this work.

BTW: $status is defined. dont worry about that.

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Little Bobby Tables' mother would be cross with you.

Answer (score 0):

You UPDATE syntax is wrong.

```
UPDATE blog_members 
SET status=-- status information 
WHERE user_id=--identifying who the status belongs to
```

[MySQL manual entry on UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)